# Tkinter Python - Remove Widgets based on Comboxbox condition

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, widget, label

I am trying to write a Python Tkinter program to display/remove a Label and Entry based on Combobox condition, it is working fine for display but for remove/hide it is not working.

```
def on_field_change(index, value, op):
    var_select_combo = box.current()
    serv_label = Label(frame1, text="Servive Name")
    E3 = Entry(frame1, bd=5)
    if var_select_combo == 1:
        serv_label.grid(row=3)
        E3.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)
    if var_select_combo == 0:
        serv_label.grid_forget()
        E3.grid_forget()

L3 = Label(frame1, text="Database")
L3.grid(row=0,pady=10)
box_value = StringVar()
box_value.trace('w',on_field_change)
box = ttk.Combobox(frame1, text="Database", textvariable=box_value,
                            state='readonly')
box['values'] = ('Teradata','Oracle')
box.current(0)
box.grid(column=1, row=0,pady=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create widgets inside `if` and you have to assign them to global variables.

Now when you choose to remove you create second pair of widgets  (because you create it before `if`) and then you remove this second pair but first pair is still visible - but you don't have access to first pair because you didn't assign them to global variables.

You can also create widgets only once - at start - and later only show and hide it.

```
def on_field_change(index, value, op):
    var_select_combo = box.current()
    if var_select_combo == 1:
        serv_label.grid(row=3)
        E3.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)
    else:
        serv_label.grid_forget()
        E3.grid_forget()

# create at start assigned to global variables
serv_label = Label(frame1, text="Servive Name")
E3 = Entry(frame1, bd=5)
```